# Maximization problem on an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, optimization, self-learning, numerical-optimization

for three variables,

$$\max f(x,y,z)= xyz \\ \text{s.t.} \ \  (\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+(\frac{z}{c})^2=1$$

where $a,b,c$ are constant

how to solve the maximization optimization problem?

thank you for helpin

Comment: Maximization optimization is redundant.  I will edit the title to make it a little more informative.

Comment: @hardmath okay you can change it by a proper /  good title :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: One way is symmetrization via change of variable $s=\frac{x}{a},t=\frac{y}{b},u=\frac{z}{c}$ and then optimize.

$\max f(s,t,u)=(abc)stu\,\,\text{subject to:  }   s^2+t^2+u^2=1.$
You can either use calculus or the fact that optimal point is of form $(\lambda,\lambda,\lambda)$. Thus $s=t=u=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ so $(x,y,z)=(\frac{a}{\sqrt 3},\frac{b}{\sqrt 3},\frac{c}{\sqrt 3})$.

In order to verify your answer you can use [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) (second derivative test)

Comment: dear BigM, what is the difference of solution for maximization problem from the solution for minimization problem. I know its solution for minimization problem. But, maximization problem?

Comment: Thanks for helping. but please show its full- solution. Because i can never see maximization problem solution.

Comment: Okay thank you. I found these values.

Comment: I want to check my answer. For this, I'm using Hessian matrix. Well, will I take second derivatives of function F(x,y,z) or of Lagrange function $L(x,y,z,\lambda)$? which one?

Comment: I need to say $(1/\sqrt 3, 1/\sqrt 3, 1/\sqrt 3)$ is maximizer of F  w.r.t the costraint. But how?

Comment: It satisfies the constraint. More over you can consider the Hessian matrix as I said and argue based on that to show that it is indeed the maximizer.